Gradio top to bottom page run on page reload?
I am writing a simple code and observed that gradio does not run top to bottom on reloading page.
for example my code structure is below of a multimodal chatbot.
print("restarted")

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
...custom code...

demo.launch()

Everytime I reload browser, it doesnt print restarted. Only prints the first time. How to make all code reload on webpage reload as I want to reset some variables.
